# Enable JQuery Sortable on dropdown select

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am currently using  jQuery sortable to rearrange table rows in my application. I have this all working fine except I need to introduce functionality where dragging is only enabled when the user selects a team from a drop-down box on the page. The idea is that when the user first arrives onto the view, a list of team rows will be displayed. They user can select a unique team from the dropdown and filter all the rows associated with that particular team. This is when I want to be able to enable the sortable functionality. I am using the sortable library in an Angular directive, and I am filtering all table rows in the Angular controller. If someone could please point me in the right direction I would be extremely grateful. Here is my code:

```html
myTeam.html

<div class="row">
    <!-- Header Start -->
    <banner-directive banner-title="Favorite Teams">
    </banner-directive>
    <!-- Header End -->
    <div id="wrap">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="team-order">
                    <div class="team-select-wrapper" style="display: inline-block">
                        <h2>Select team</h2>
                        <select class="form-control" name="teamList" ng-model="selectedteam" ng-options="team as team.name for team in teams" ng-change="onTeamSelected()">
                            <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Team</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <strong>{{teammatches.length}}</strong>Teams:
                </div>
                <team-order-matches matches="teammatches" teamorder="teamorder"></team-order-matches>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="team-order-matches">
    <div class="content">
        <table class="table" id="draggable_rows">
            <thead style="position: fixed;  top:182px;">
            <tr>
                <th class="table-col-medium">
                   Name

                </th>
                <th class="table-col-medium">
                   Team

                </th>
                <th class="table-col-medium">
                   Amount

                </th>
                <th class="table-col-large">
                    Win
                </th>
                <th class="table-col-medium">
                    Loss
                </th>
                <th class="table-col-medium">
                  Draw
                </th>
                <th class="table-col-medium">
                    Manager
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat-start="team in teams" class="team-order-row" id="{{team._id}}">
                <td class="table-col-medium" style="position: relative;">
                    Name
                </td>
                <td class="table-col-medium">
                   Example
                </td>
                <td class="table-col-medium">
                    Example
                </td>
                <td class="table-col-large">
                    Example
                </td>
                <td class="table-col-medium">
                   Example
                </td>
                <td class="table-col-medium">
                    Example
                </td>
                <td class="table-col-medium">
                    Example
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my controller

```
function TeamOrderMatchesController($scope,$location, $filter, $window, LocaleService) {


    $scope.teammatches = [];
    $scope.sortColumn = sortColumn;
    $scope.onTeamSelected = onTeamSelected;



    //filters the list to team that is selected
    function onTeamSelected(){
        TeamService.getMatchEvalOrder($scope.selectedteam._id).then(function(result){
            $scope.runorder = result.result;
            $scope.teammatches = orderByEvalOrder($scope.runorder, filterMatchesByTeam())
        });


    }


    //Gets the unique team list for the dropdown menu
    function getTeamList(){
        var teams =  _.map($scope.matches, function(match){
            var liveVersion = _.find(match.versions, function(version){
                return match.liveVersion === version.version;
            });
            return liveVersion.team;
        });
        var uniqueTeams = _.uniq(teams, function(team){
            return team._id;
        });
        return uniqueTeams;

    }

    //Captures the evaluation order of the rows dragged and dropped
    function orderByEvalOrder(orderedMatchIds, matches) {

        var orderedMatches = [];

        if(orderedMatchIds && orderedMatchIds.length > 0){
            _.each(orderedMatchIds, function(orderedmatch){
                var foundMatch = _.find(matches, function(m) {
                    return m._id == orderedmatch;
                });
                if(foundMatch) {
                    orderedMatches.push(foundMatch);
                }
            });

            _.each(matches, function(match){
                if (orderedMatchIds.indexOf(match._id) < 0) {
                    orderedMatches.push(match);
                }
            });

        }
        else{
            orderedMatches = matches;
        }
        return orderedMatches;
    }



    //Filters the matches on the team selected
    function filterMatchesByTeam() {
        return _.filter($scope.matches, function(match){

            var liveVersion = _.find(match.versions, function (version) {
                return match.liveVersion === version.version;
            });
            return liveVersion.team._id === $scope.selectedteam._id;
        });
    }


    function sortColumn(predicate, reverse) {

        $scope.sortedColumn = predicate;
        $scope.matches = $filter('orderBy')($scope.matches, matchPredicate, reverse);

        function matchPredicate(match) {
            var column;

            if (shouldSortOnRoot()) {
                column = match[predicate];
            } else {
                setVersionColumn();
            }

            return column;

            function shouldSortOnRoot() {
                return match.hasOwnProperty(predicate);
            }

            function setVersionColumn() {

                var tempColumn = getLiveVersion(match)[predicate];

                if (tempColumn.name) {
                    column = tempColumn.name;
                } else {
                    column = tempColumn;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
enter code here
```

exampleApp.directive('teamOrderMatches',[ '_',teamOrderMatches]);

function teamOrderMatches(_) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            onsave: '&',
            oncancel: '&',
            matches: '=',
            isDraggable: '&',
            runorder: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem){
            var table = elem.find("#draggable_rows tbody");
            function updateScope() {
                var ids = _.map(table.children(), function(child){
                    return child.id;
                });

```
            var idsWithoutEmpty = _.filter(ids, function(id) {
                return id && id !== "";
            });

            scope.runorder = idsWithoutEmpty;
            console.log(scope.teamorder);

            scope.$apply();
        }

        table.sortable({
            axis: 'y',
            items: 'tr',
            connectWith: 'table',
            placeholder: "highlight",
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            scroll: true,
            sort: function(event, ui) {
                var currentScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
                    topHelper = ui.position.top,
                    delta = topHelper - currentScrollTop;
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(window).scrollTop(currentScrollTop + delta);
                }, 5);
            },
            //Helper function to keep table from collapsing when being sorted
            helper: function(e, tr){
            var $originals = tr.children();
            var $helper = tr.clone().addClass('clone');
            $helper.children().each(function(index)
            {
                $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width());
            });
            return $helper;
        },
            //The update function will update the table rows scope after they have been dragged to a new position
            update: function(){
                updateScope();
            }
        }).disableSelection();

    },


    controller: 'TeamOrderMatchesController'
};
```

}

Comment: That's a lot of code, most of which doesn't look like it's relevant to the question ("getTeamList"?)  (might be, but too much to determine).  Is it possible to provide only the relevant code?  Read this for more info:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what sortable library is used, but generally there are events that fire (eg start/change/over/out/update/stop) - it should be possible to listen into one or more of these and cancel the sort if the team hasn't yet been picked.  Alternatively, it might be possible to defer the initialisation of the sort until a team has been picked.  (As I understand it) Angular is generally just jquery but triggered by tag properties - so it should be possible to make the same triggers manually.